# Tailwind breakpoints not working with Next.js SSG

Tags: reactjs, next.js, css-grid, tailwind-css, postcss

I have a `/latest` page in my `pages` directory which displays all the latest posts. But my Tailwind classes (`grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 2xl:grid-cols-4 gap-4`) don't want to work. Here is a side by side comparison of the issue I'm having:

| Local Version | Production Version |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Local Version] | [image: Production Version] |

My component looks like this (`./pages/latest.tsx`):

```js
const Latest: React.FC<LatestProps> = ({}) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation('latest')
  const { data, loading } = useFindLatestQuery()

  return (
    <>
      <Navigation />
      <DefaultWrapper>
        <div className="w-full">
          <div className="w-full flex justify-center">
            <h1>{t('recent')}</h1>
          </div>
          {!loading && data?.posts?.length > 0 ? (
            <div className="mt-6 grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 2xl:grid-cols-4 gap-4">
              {[...data.posts].map((post, index) => (
                <SearchedPost key={index} post={post as unknown as Post} />
              ))}
            </div>
          ) : (
            <p>Loading...</p>
          )}
        </div>
      </DefaultWrapper>
    </>
  )
}
```

Here's a [link](https://staging-blog.vercel.app/_next/static/css/1e7d88fbb79f595588a0.css) to the production CSS generated by Tailwind, and you'll see that there's nothing related to `grid`. Here's also a [link](https://staging-blog.vercel.app/en-US/latest) to that build.

Tailwind Config:

```js
module.exports = {
  // mode: 'jit',
  purge: [
    './components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
    './pages/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
    './icons/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
  ],
  darkMode: 'class', // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: In your production css there is no grid class, double check your tailwind setup.

Comment: @herbie vine did you figure out why? I am having similar issue, some of the breakpoints are not working.

Comment: am looking at what I did. it's been a while so need to look at my cryptic programming again haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for why this error occurred, I honestly don't know.

I looked back at the source code. The very first commit of this code was [here](https://github.com/herbievine/blog/commit/ac087cd85f2a157c3668cce2ca956baf52502a49#diff-255570e679e0d78e5e4f28b24e64b2d25cb2aba6f5b03f3e9f82c221173581e5R17-R35), and it hasn't really changed since. I also redeployed that specific commit, and all worked fine. The error must have been cached-related. I'll post all the links and commits below:

---

### Production version

- [Link](https://blog.herbievine.com/fr-FR/latest)
- [CSS file for that page](https://blog.herbievine.com/_next/static/css/837f352d28ebe253acc6.css)
- [`./pages/latest.tsx` on GitHub](https://github.com/herbievine/blog/blob/main/pages/latest.tsx)

---

### Staging version (which had the error)

- [Link](https://staging-blog.vercel.app/en-US/latest)
- [CSS file for that page](https://staging-blog.vercel.app/_next/static/css/837f352d28ebe253acc6.css)
- [`./pages/latest.tsx` on GitHub](https://github.com/herbievine/blog/blob/ac087cd85f2a157c3668cce2ca956baf52502a49/pages/latest.tsx)

---

Sorry if this doesn't help your bug. Feel free to snoop around the [repo](https://github.com/herbievine/blog) where I had the error and/or comment :)

Comment: @avepr hope this helps you out